# / permissions on a linux filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, nfs

Does the `/` have permissions attached to it? If so what are they and what command do you run to find out?

The reason why I ask this is to know weather a NFS mount reflect this if your export is set to `/ 192.100.0.0/24(....)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the / have permissions attached to it?

Of course. It's a directory, like any other.

> what are they

Two very different systems here show 755, but I don't see any reason it couldn't be something else for another system.

The owner is almost certainly going to be `root`, but the group is likely to vary between different system types. One of mine is group `root`, and the other is group `wheel`.

> what command do you run to find out?

`$ ls -ld /`

Comment: Ahh hense the fact why I wasnt getting `rw` on a mounted `/` as my `/` is `dr-xr-xr-x`